# Stockfish engine in flutter

Tags: c++, flutter, dart, artificial-intelligence, chess

I started a project about chess and I wanted to let the user play with the computer (AI), I searched a lot about an engine to use it as an AI, I found a stockfish engine but I can't find anything about how to use it into your flutter project.
so how to use it into my flutter project (steps) and what's the requirement of using it,
and is there any resource or documentation about stockfish in general or for flutter?

-thanks for helping me for solving this probplem

i want to find a way to use stockfish engine into my flutter project

Comment: How is this related to C++?